# Prometheus/Alert manager - Getting Node down Alert which is not a node in the cluster

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

We are getting the node alert which is not in the EKS cluster nodes.
The Alert manager rule is as below.

```
- alert: InstanceDown
  expr: up == 0
  for: 0m            # Given 5m, and 10m even its same
  labels:
    severity: critical
  annotations:
    summary: “Instance [{{ $labels.instance }}] down”
    description: “Instance [{{ $labels.instance }}] down”
```

and the mail we got as in the [image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXCN8.png)

which are not the nodes in Eks.

And when i check in Prometheus dashboard and query "up==0"
then i got the above table data as in the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mkDR.png)

And here what i got to know is that the ips coming here are older pod ips that are restarted or removed from the Kube-system namespace.
So why am getting the alert for pods that happens before (more than a month back)? Is that data is not updated or flushed each time to get new by the rule scrape of Prometheus?